# Ping/print successful, cannot scan to network or access web interface for printer

Tags: printer, network-printer

We have an odd issue with one of our printers. As stated in the title, we can ping the printer, run a traceroute, can print and even scan if we use the Brother Control Center app but we're switching over to scanning all documents into a shared share folder on the network.

When someone attempts to use the "scan to network" feature on the printer, it usually takes about 5 minutes stuck on the "Connecting...." screen and eventually times out. All the network scan settings are identical to others we use in a different office and I triple checked all the credentials, DC IP address, FS IP address, etc, everything appears to be correct.

The weird thing is, if we power cycle the printer, I am able to get into the printer's web interface for about 1-2mins then the connection times out and I can't access it for several hours. It'll eventually load, i'll be able to do a few things on the interface before the connection stops again.

I've done firmware upgrades, changed the dhcp reservation to a different ip thinking it may be an ip address conflict, and eventually restored the device back to factory default to purge it of all settings. We attempted to ping the printer from various devices on the same subnet and different subnet but same physical location, everything appears to be fine. Nothing worked so we assumed it was an issue with the printer itself, so we purchased a new one only to find the same symptoms. I'm not sure what else we can try/check at this point. Has anyone experienced this issue? I've done a bunch of research and contacted brother support several times but they have not been much help they just kept saying it's a problem with our router...i assume if this was the case all our other devices connected to the same switch and/or router would be experiencing connectivity issues but nothing else is broken..

Comment: Please provide full network settings of the device and a computer including mask, gateway, DNS server and DNS server type

Comment: Have you set up a user for the printer to use when writing to the network drive? Are you able to provide the make and model of the printer?

Comment: we're using a Brother MFC-L8600CDW. We have a service account we use that has r/w permissions to the share, but really i dont think that part matters because the everyone group also has r/w. It's just a generic share for all users to dump scans into.

Printer:
IP: 192.168.170.20
Mask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.170.1
Dns(primary): 192.168.172.8
Dns(secondary): 192.168.172.9

I've left the auth method for the scan options under "Auto", user account name as user@domain.local and domain\username (neither made a difference). Entered in kerberos/DC FQDN, no dice.

Comment: dns server running on winsrv2012 r2..just a side note, ran packet capture on the switchport it came up with some odd stuff, I will post the output here in a bit..never really done packet captures so learning this stuff as i go